# JavaBean and SQL

Tags: java, javabeans

I have create a JavaBean and I want to connect my bean with my database, so I created a insert method inside of the bean. My code look like:

```
public class Persona implements Serializable {

private String dni;
private String nombre;

public Persona() {

dni = "";
nombre = "";

}

public String getDni() {
    return dni;
}

public void setDni(String dni) {
    this.dni = dni;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

   public int anadirClientes(){

    int result=0;

    String insert = " INSERT INTO PERSONAS(dni, nombre) VALUES ('"+getDni()+"','"
            +getNombre()+"')";

    try {  
         result = crearConeccion().executeUpdate(insert);    
         crearConeccion().close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Clientes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return result;
}
```

But I don´t know if it´s correct, o I should create the insert method in the main class.

Comment: Maybe you should look at DAO design pattern or Repository design pattern https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html

Comment: @flox95 So you mean to create a class call PersonaDAO, that connect with database, and in the method of this class, i should use the bean, that´s right?

Comment: Better yet, `JdbcTemplate` or JPA.

Comment: @Charles106 Yes i mean you should follow the pattern principles by using a generic interface that provide CRUD operation (Create Read Update Delete) and a DAO implementing class using JDBC. https://dzone.com/articles/building-simple-data-access-layer-using-jdbc

Comment: @flox95 i will try that, thank you